# Cisco ansible show running-config

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

As per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_config_module.html#parameter-defaults), this should fetch the running config by running show running-config all

```
      cisco.ios.ios_config:
        defaults: yes
```

It ends up erroring out with

```
"msg": "show running-config ?\\r\\n% Unrecognized command\\r\\nRTCISCO1111>show running-config \\r\\nshow running-config \\r\\n      ^\\r\\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\\r\\n\\r\\nRTCISCO1111>"
}
```

I traced the command `show running-config ?` to https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/plugins/cliconf/ios.py#L455
In this part of the code I do not understand why its not substituting `?` with `all`.
Do I need to supply some additional commands?
I cannot run `show running-config all` as shell command because it required root access on device.

Comment: Can you update with your entire playbook ? To see your connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco requires `enable mode` to run `show running-config all` command. Getting into enable mode requires another password.

Some examples on how to use in playbook are here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html